# R combn function

Tags: r, combn

I am stuck with the following code. I am trying to make combinations of 3 rows from 5 rows declared. But the combn function is not working
It's showing *combin not found*. If I declare it above as array, it is showing *non-conformable array*

```
ret <- data.frame(ibm_rt,cisco_rt,ebay_rt,oracle_rt,msft_rt)
ret
combin <- combn(ret,3,rowSums, simplify = TRUE)
combin
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce the error. It works with a 5 columns df. Can you post the output of `dput(head(ret, 10))`, please?

Comment: structure(list(ibm_rt = c ........row.names = c(NA, 
10L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: You didn't understand, post the output of `dput(head(ret, 10))` **in the question**, please. This will give us an exact copy of the data structure.

Answer (score 0):

@NirJ
The first argument need to be vector to the combn function. Therefore, you should consider passing column name instead of entire dataframe.

e.g.

```
combin < - combn(ret$Column_name,3,rowSums, simplify = TRUE)
```

`combin`

Comment: Here, I have to select 3 columns from 5. Then I can't pass column name as the input even if I declare one. Please help

Comment: Can you make one list by appending all the five columns? Can you add example of the datatype and data?